# EJB, JPA, JSF why can't get a new bean to view

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, ejb-3.0, ejb-3.1

I need your help

1. I have a ManagedBean

   ```
   @ManagedBean
   @SessionScoped
   public class ComponentController implements Serializable {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 373631006594351707L;
   @EJB
   IComponentService componentService;
   @EJB
   IDocumentService documentService;
   private Component component;
   private DocumentEntity document;



   public String createAndClose() {
       componentService.save(component);
       FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Component added.", null);
       FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
       component = new Component();
       return "components";
   }

   public String saveAndClose() {
       componentService.update(component);
       FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Component updated.", null);
       FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
       component = new Component();
       return "components";
   }

   public String createView() {
       component = new Component();
       return "create";
   }

   }
   ```
2. I have a generic dao service like this

   ```
   public abstract class GenericJpaService<T extends BaseEntity, ID extends Serializable> implements IGenericService<T, ID> {

       @PersistenceContext
       EntityManager em;
       private Class<T> persistentClass;

       public GenericJpaService() {
       }

       public GenericJpaService(Class<T> persistentClass) {
           this.persistentClass = persistentClass;
       }

       public Class<T> getPersistentClass() {
           return persistentClass;
       }

       public void setPersistentClass(Class<T> persistentClass) {
           this.persistentClass = persistentClass;
       }

       @Override
       public T save(T entity) {
           this.em.persist(entity);
           this.em.flush();
           this.em.refresh(entity);
           Logger.getLogger(GenericJpaService.class.getName()).log(Level.INFO, "Object {0} saved to DB", entity);
           return entity;
       }

       @Override
       @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
       public T update(T entity) {
           Logger.getLogger(GenericJpaService.class.getName()).log(Level.INFO, "Object {0} updated in DB", entity);
           return (T) this.em.merge(entity);
       }
   ...
   }
   ```
3. So when I run application first I click on some link **Add component**. It execute:

> public String createView()

1. I add there some data + upload some files etc...
2. Then I click save and close button. It execute:

> public String createAndClose()

1. Successfully it save my data to database.

And here is a problem when I do it again it show me data which I save before. I debug it but I do not understand where it is set. After

> public String createView()

it shoud take new Component() for jsf page.
So where I make a mistake? What I still do not understand? Maybe I shoud use Hibernate instead plain JPA? I use it (Hibernate) before so it was easier (with HibernateUtil).

PS. Sorry for multiple instance of "new Component()" but I'm trying put it everywhere...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest flaw is that you're using the session scope, but have instance variables that are clearly intended for a single view.

Use @ViewScoped or see if you can rewrite the code so you can use @RequestScoped.

A small other hint; when saving it's not needed to do a flush and refresh. This already happens automatically. Refresh also does not update the given entity, but returns a fresh one. Just calling em.refresh thus doesn't make sense here.

Comment: Ok I change it to ViewScoped. And change from ManagedBean to Named. It works. My scenario work fine. Now problem is different but I will put the description below.

Comment: @toldi be aware that view scoped does NOT work in JSF 2.1 and below in combination with Named. You are probably using request scope now.

Comment: I found it yesterday.  <br/> I read this and it help me undarstand:   <br/> 
http://germanescobar.net/2010/04/4-areas-of-possible-confusion-in-jee6.html/ <br/>
Thank you very much @MikeBraun